# regex limit character extraction chars to 150

Tags: regex

The code I am currently using is:

```
(?<=<STRONG>Description:</STRONG>)[\w\s\/\,\.\-\?\(\)\£\!\'\’]*
```

The text I am extracting can vary from 0 - 3000 I am using regex and I wish to limit text 150 characters I tried adding {0,150} but received errors

Comment: what errors did you recieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=<STRONG>Description:</STRONG>)[\w\s\/\,\.\-\?\(\)\£\!\'\’]{0,150}
```

You have to remove the `*`.

Another thing, this will limit the length of the matched string to 150 characters, it will match it even if it's longer.

Comment: @Florian: He said he added that. This means he didn't remove the `*`.

Comment: thats worked perfectly didn't remove the * which caused the error.  sorry and thanks